# How can I add CSS files into react-native app without using styleSheet native elements

Tags: css, react-native

I need to add pure `CSS` files into the react-native android and ios app. How to overcome this problem without using styleSheet native elements?.

```
body {
   margin: 25px;
   background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can,

Try using [css-to-react-native](http://%20https://github.com/styled-components/css-to-react-native)

Converts CSS text to a React Native stylesheet object.

```
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
color: red;
```

to

```
{
  fontSize: 18,
  lineHeight: 24,
  color: 'red',
}
```

Converts all number-like values to numbers, and string-like to strings.

```
import transform from 'css-to-react-native';
// or const transform = require('css-to-react-native').default;

transform([
  ['font', 'bold 14px/16px "Helvetica"'],
  ['margin', '5px 7px 2px'],
  ['border-left-width', '5px'],
]); // => { fontFamily: 'Helvetica', ... }
```

Another alternative is  [react-native-css-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-css-transformer)

Comment: How to call this border-left-width in the component ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`styled-components`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics).

Then you can code using css for the component styles.

```
const Body = styled.body`
   margin: 25px;
   background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
`;

const Header = styled.h1`
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 5px;
`;
```